# Change a div content if datetime is set with condition (Without refreshing the page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an issue with my code. My scenario is, let say current DateTime is 2020-06-24 09:15:00 and the wording in div is "Off Air". But when the current DateTime is 2020-06-24 10:00:00, the div will change to "On Air" without refreshing the page. Below is my code

index.php

```
<?php

        echo $current = date('d-M-Y H:i A');

        echo "<br>";

        echo $start = '24-Jun-2020 02:56 AM';

        echo "<br>";

        if($start <= $current ) {

        echo '<div>
                <h1 style="color:green;">On Air</h1>

        </div>';

        }else{

            echo '<div>
                <h1 style="color:red;">Off Air</h1>

        </div>';
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to your problem.

1. You need to continuously keep track of the time, and
2. You have to do something once the target time has come around.

So basically what you want to do is to fire a function on a set interval and when it runs, check the current date and time. Then if your condition is met, you can use Javacript to change the contents of the div. remember to set the text back to default when you are outside the target times.